# Would reading a seforim catalog in the bathroom be prohibited?

Tags: torah-study, bathroom

You aren't supposed to study Torah or even think about Torah thoughts while in a place of uncleanliness, such as the bathroom. (See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.4.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.5.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).)

But what about a catalog that sells seforim such as ArtScroll? Could you read something like that in the bathroom, since your primary reason for looking at it is so you could buy a Torah book?

Comment: Does it have torah printed in it - e.g. photos of pages of the seforim?

Comment: Perhaps this sounds "trivial", but if you're not allowed to even "think Torah thoughts", and you're looking at a catalog that lists Torah books, and you're thinking of buying a book ... aren't you thinking Torah thoughts, already? Or, do you just like looking at random pictures of books?